# Non-matching colors for arrows in matplotlib 3D quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm having this weird problem with coloring the arrows on a matplotlib 3d quiver plot.

The following minimum example correctly colors the base (from the scatter plot) the shaft and the ends of the arrows with the same color

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

sp = 0.501
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(-0.5, 1, sp), np.arange(-0.5, 1, sp), np.arange(-0.5, 1, sp)
)

X = x.ravel()
Y = y.ravel()
Z = z.ravel()

# Make some direction and size data for the arrows
C = np.random.random(X.shape)
U = Y * C
V = np.zeros_like(U)
W = np.zeros_like(U)

# Color
np.random.seed(0)
col = np.random.random(X.shape)
# Normalize
c1 = (col - col.min()) / col.ptp()
cm1 = plt.cm.hsv(c1)
# Repeat colors for each body line and two head lines
c3 = np.concatenate((c1, np.repeat(c1, 2)))
cm3 = plt.cm.hsv(c3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax3.scatter(X, Y, Z, s=5, c=cm1)
ax3.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, length=0.5, colors=cm3)
plt.show()
```

And gives this plot

[image: colors match]

If I change the first line to `sp =0.500`
The colors no longer match

[image: colors do not match]

In each case the same values in the `cm3` array are passed to the `colors` parameter of `quiver`

Answer (score 1):

The way you've specified colours looks right. I think there's an issue with the direction component `U`. Not sure why, but adding a vanishingly small offset fixes it: `U = U + 1e-10`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, without looking a the source it smells like a divide by zero error with maybe the nan being dropped for the main color but not the arrow heads.